# Schengen Visa question (multiple legs involving non-schengen countries)

Tags: visas, schengen, europe

I will be travelling to Iceland -> Ireland -> UK -> France (in that order) in the span of about 2 weeks this summer, and unfortunately I need a separate visa for each country (basic tourist/short visit visa)

However, I saw that Iceland and France are schengen countries, and was wondering if I could use 1 visa to visit both countries, even though I am visting two countries out of the schengen program in between.

Would love to save both time & money by only applying for 1, rather than 2 separate schengen visas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly possible through a multiple entry uniform Schengen visa.

A uniform Schengen visa allows you to enter and transit through any of the Schengen states (including Iceland and France) for as long as the visa is valid. However, as you will be exiting the Schengen area, and then re-entering it at a later date, you will require a visa that allows you at least two entries.

To accomplish this, simply indicate the number of entries you require (2 or multiple) on the Schengen visa form, and justify the number of entries you have requested by providing proof of your need to leave and enter the Schengen area multiple times. In accordance with European visa regulations, do make sure that you apply to the Schengen consulate that you will be spending more time in (i.e., apply to the Icelandic embassy if you plan to spend more traveling days there, otherwise apply to France).

Comment: Great - thank you so much!  That was quite helpful (and succinct!).

Comment: @J.Garcia You're very welcome. Happy that I could help.